# Dúvida Consulta SQL via chave primária no PHP?

Tags: php, sql, query

Estou iniciando na linguagem PHP, e preciso retornar uma simples consulta feita no sql a partir de uma variável que recebe o valor digitado pelo usuário. Sendo que, só ira exibir o resultado da busca por chave primária. Porém no código abaixo o que você digita no campo `$buscar` cai direto no `else`, como que se todo o valor que eu colocasse de chave primária no campo `$buscar` fosse `null`. Conseguem me ajudar?

**Obs:** A consulta no sql está funcionando, ex.: `select * from empresa where cod = 123;`

```
<?php
      $buscar = $_POST['buscar'];
      $sql = mysqli_query ($conexao, "SELECT * FROM loja where COD = '%$buscar%' ");


      $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

      if ($row != 0 && $row < 900) {

          while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql)) {
              $nome = $linha ['nome'];
              $contato = $linha['contato'];
              $endereco = $linha['endereco'];
              $coordenador = $linha['coordenador'];

              echo "<br /> <br  />";
              echo "<strong>  Contato:      </strong>".$nome;
              echo "<strong>  Contato:      </strong>".$contato;
              echo "<strong>  Coordenador:  </strong>".$coordenador;
              echo "<strong>  Endereço:     </strong>".$endereco;

          }

      } else {
        echo "Desculpe nenhum registro encontrado";

      }


?>
```

Comment: Se o `COD` for um `int` você não conseguirá fazer o `LIKE`, digo isso porque o `COD` parece ser `Codigo`, que normalmente é numero (e o seu exemplo também é número). Na verdade, nem `LIKE` está sendo utilizado, você está usando apenas uma string qualquer contendo o `%`, que não é um número inteiro. Não dá para entender o que quer fazer, até porque você menciona que remover o `%` resolve.

Comment: Entendi, realmente não prestei atenção no %, pois como não estou utilizando um like não teria necessidade de colocar.. Após remover o % a pesquisa no cod = codigo (rsrs)  funcionou. Muito obrigado !

Comment: O `LIKE` funciona sim numa coluna de inteiro, o problema em fazer o `LIKE` é encontrar qualquer número que pareça com o que você está pesquisando, por exemplo, numa pesquisa do número `23` todos os códigos que tem `23` no começo, meio ou fim retornariam no resultado, veja esse [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c573bd/1). No seu código só não funciona porque colocou `= '%$buscar%` sendo que deveria ser `LIKE '%$buscar%'`.

Comment: @LaércioLopes, bem apontado, acredito que agora ele deva fazer algum CAST internamente, nas versões mais novas, mas tenho quase certeza de que isso não era possível antes. Mesmo assim, não faz menor sentido fazer isso. Mas, o problema era mesmo a presença do `%`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($conexao, "SELECT * FROM loja where COD = {$buscar}");
```